# How do you calculate interest on a loan with different rates?

Tags: c, if-statement, calculator

I think it's obvious I don't understand. How do you tell the computer in C to decide which is the appropriate interest rate and then calculate and display it. This is the best I could come up with and I have to hand this as an assignment tomorrow. I had not clue it would be this difficult.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    float time;
    float principal;
    char response[15];
    float rate1, rate2,rate3,rate4;
    rate1=.04,rate2=.05,rate3=.06,rate4=.07;

    float SimpleInterest1;
    float SimpleInterest2;
    float SimpleInterest3;
    float SimpleInterest4;

    SimpleInterest1=principal*time*rate1;
    SimpleInterest2=principal*time*rate2;
    SimpleInterest1=principal*time*rate3;
    SimpleInterest2=principal*time*rate4;


    printf("Please enter principal\n");
    scanf ("%f",&principal);
    printf ("Please enter time\n");
    scanf ("%f",&time);

    if (principal <= 5000)
{

    printf ("%f",&SimpleInterest1);
}
    printf ("Do you still want the loan?\n");
    scanf ("%s",response);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's worse than you think. Floating-point math is not adequate for financial calculations.

Comment: what would you recommend? it's supposed to be a beginner class but it seems a bit challenging. All we've been taught so far is differences between string,integers, floats, if, while, and some problem solving. can it be done with those methods?

Comment: See [Loan payment formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loan#Loan_payment).  Round money values and resultant calculations as needed to the nearest minor unit like 0.01.  Do not use `float`.  `double` is better.

Comment: @RaphaelJones What do you expect from this to be calculated? `SimpleInterest1=principal*time*rate1`

Comment: Well, for a homework assignment you can probably go with floating-point math, unless you've explicitly been told not to. So, you're wondering how to interact with your program, do input/output?

Comment: the question is. A bank pays interest on amount of money deposited.If the amount is less than 5000, the interest is %4 per annum. If the amount is $5000 or more but less than $10,000, the interest is 5%per annum. And so on. I don't know how to structure the formula so the computer returns the answer. It's syntax i need help with please?

Comment: `float interest; if (principal < 5000) interest = 0.04; else if (principal < 10000) interest = 0.05; else interest = whateveryouwant;`

Comment: Your comment is about a bank deposit.  The post title is about a loan.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been already said: do not forget to ask for `principal` value using
`scanf`.

Then, use if-else if-else-statements to know in which interval `principal` lies.
Then, inside each statement, assign `interest` to the right value.

Then assign `time` to the right value (you can `scanf` it if you have to) before calculating the interest.

Also, check if the interest has to be recomputed each year on the
new debt. If this is the case, then the formula should be
`debt = principal * (1 + rate)^time`.
You can `#include <math.h>` to use the `pow` function that computes the power of a float or a double.

Then just `printf("%f", debt);`.

*Aparté:*
Michael Overton's book "Numerical Computing with IEEE Arithmetic" pp.82-86 explains pretty well how to compute a compound interest with a stable algorithm, because the *naive* way to compute it using `pow` can involve a loss of accuracy.

Comment: He's calculating simple interest

Comment: I'm not sure about that. See [Raphael Jones' comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143891/how-do-you-calculate-interest-on-a-loan-with-different-rates/28148811?noredirect=1#comment44659772_28143891)

Comment: Different interest rates based on the principal, you misinterpreted

Answer (score 0):

First off, these two lines are probably a typo:

```
SimpleInterest1=principal*time*rate3;
SimpleInterest2=principal*time*rate4;
```

They should become this:

```
SimpleInterest3=principal*time*rate3;
SimpleInterest4=principal*time*rate4;
```

Next, if your asking about i/o (input/output), then here's a basic run through:

You use `printf( char *format, ...)` to output information.

You use `scanf( char *format, ...)` to do basic input.

Where format is one of the following (this is the basics):

```
%s : Argument is expected to be of type char*
%i : Argument is expected to be signed int
%f : Argument is expected to be float (use also for double in printf)
%u : Argument is expected to be unsinged int.
```

When you use scanf, you should check the return value and clear the input buffer, examples will follow:

```
void clear_buffer() {
  // Note that ch is int not char, this is important
  int ch;
  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}

int answers = 0;
float value = 0.0;
do {
  // Scanf returns the recieved number of args that fit the format string
  answers = scanf( "%f", &value );
  clear_buffer();
  if (answers == 0) {
    continue;
  }
} while (value > -0.1 && value < 0.1);
```

The above may not work as I mainly work with unsigned integers, but it should provide a good foundation at the very least.

You use if...else if....else to determine the formula to use.

Lastly, you should calculate the SimpleInterest AFTER you get a value for time and principal; the c parser cannot **'see into the future'**

Comment: Don't forget to query the value of the prinicipal and determine the interest based off of that.

Comment: @RaphaelJones See the end of my post, that was where the biggest problem in your program was -- principal and time had not been defined yet!